# Slow sudo and ssmtp (hosts file wrong?)

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, sudo, hosts-file

I'm running an Ubuntu Server 12.04.5 LTS and when I type `sudo su` it takes 30+ seconds to open  the shell. Searching on internet, this problem seems related to the file `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname`.

This isn't really a problem for me to wait, however this is affecting other programs (especially sSMTP wich I use for sending mails from PHP) and Apache is giving the classical "*could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name*".

So I've checked the hosts file and corrected it, and now the apache error is gone but the other problems persist. `sudo su` now takes about 10-15 seconds.

Output of `uname -n`, `hostname` and `hostname -f` is:

```
server.example.com
```

Output of `hostname -a`:

```
server
```

Contents of `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
127.0.1.1   server.example.com      server

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

This server has a public IPv4 address and the DNS record for `server.example.com` is correct.

If I try `ping server` or `ping server.example.com` they work as expected (resolving to `127.0.1.1`)

The server is also running openvpn with less than 10 clients, but disabling the service has no consequences.

**Things tried so far:**

1) Changing hostname to "localhost": this **solves** the problem, *but isn't acceptable*;

2) This version of `/etc/hosts` (not working):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost   server.example.com
127.0.1.1   server.example.com      server

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback   server.example.com
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

3) Current version of `/etc/hosts` (not working):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
127.0.1.1       server.sistema3.it      server

::1     ip6-localhost   ip6-loopback    localhost
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I've run many servers in the past and this is the only one having this problem. I'm completely stuck, any help is very appreciated. Thanks.

I've also posted this question over to AskUbuntu, but maybe is better ServerFault for this kind of problem.

Comment: You're trying to fix the problem and jumping to conclusions without doing any diagnoses... I agree that such timeouts may very well come from name resolution trouble... Try a tcpdump on port 53 for example to see if it's doing DNS lookups that generate errors or the like: `tcpdump -i lo port 53`, `tcpdump -i eth0 port 53`...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've tried that and I see you are correct: no traffic on port 53, so the problem must be somewhere else. How can I do an `strace` if only the command `sudo su` presents the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the problem, and it wasn't a server issue.

It was a setting in the client, Putty. X11 Forwarding was enabled, and caused all the issues. Switched that off.